# Google Chart with Slim3 in google app engine (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-visualization

Has anyone used google chart with slim3? I am struggling to send the DataTable object from controller to jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this. I avoided using controller to feed my data for generating Google chart. Rather I did the followings:

1. Created a Servlet manually (In Slim3 project you cannot create a Servlet following Eclipse new menu. Instead create a regular java class and extend "DataSourceServlet". Please remember to restart your container before testing the Servlet. The servlet changes are not "Hot Reloaded".
2. Add the the servlet definition in web.xml file

     My Servlet
     My servlet description.
     SimpleExampleServlet


     My Servlet
     simpleexample
3. Call the Servlet from javascript as below:

   var query = new google.visualization.Query('simpleexample');

[If you are new on Google chart and Google visualization API, please have a look on here:](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-java/source/browse/trunk/examples/src/java/SimpleExampleServlet.java)